# Fetch previously requested URL in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

Is it possible to fetch previously called XHR request URLs (which used Angular's HttpClient)?

I'm willing to use the Interceptor. How can that be done? Pointing in the right direction might be just enough.

Having basic functionality like fetching the latest history member would be cool and basic ideas about remove, clear, add methods would be nice too.

Comment: Yes it is possible

Comment: @Liam Nice, how can it be done?

Comment: You don't seem to have asked that quesion? Your question also [lacks effort](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/). If you want help, you need to make a better effort yourself

Comment: I edited my question accordingly

Comment: You can create a service that holds the history of your requests

Comment: @PascalR. what method do I need to use to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an interceptor to achieve this. Just create a simple interceptor:

```
export class XhrInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor(private xhrHistoryService: XhrHistoryService) {}

    public intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        // Here you have the information from your call and can get/store the data
        this.xhrHistoryService.add(request.url);
        return next.handle(request).pipe(
            tap((ev: HttpEvent<any>) => {
                // If you want to log responses add here
            })
        );
    }
}
```

As you can see I injected a xhrHistoryService. This service is for keeping and managing the history. As I do not know exactly what you want to do with your history it is just an example. If you wish to use your history as kind of cache you can also do it in the interceptor directly.

```
export class XhrHistoryService {
    // Define here what types you want to log
    private history: string[] = [];

    public getAll() {
        return this.history;
    }

    public getLatest() {
        return this.history.length && this.history[this.history.length - 1];
    }

    // Define here what you want to log
    public add(url: string) {
        this.history.push(url);
    }
}
```

I hope this helps. If not, please edit your question to specify your needs.

Code is here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-atovsq?file=src/app/xhr.interceptor.ts

Comment: How do I fetch the last requested URL? this.history[idhere]? Is there a method for "grabbing" the newest array member? It would be really cool if you implemented all of the methods you wrote down like get(), remove(), clear() or at least give us a hint on how to implement it. I accepted your answer nonetheless, since you solved my main problem.

Comment: I added the getLatest() method in my post. It's just basic stuff. Maybe you should just start learning JavaScript/Typescript and ask specific questions if you're stuck. People here won't solve everything you ask for.